# Why can't I trade this Powersaved Entei away?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, cheats

I've made a whole box of cloned shiny Entei with Powersaves, and I'm trying to Wonder Trade them. I've seen so many Pokemon like Shiny Arceus being traded onto WonderTrade, why won't this Entei?

The Entei is nicknamed "*King Sacred*" and is holding a Choice Scarf
**Stats:** 180, 134, 125, 124, 149
**Ability:** Pressure
**Nature:** Adamant
**Ball:** Premier Ball

- Sacred Fire
- Iron Head
- Stone Edge
- Bulldoze

I cloned all of them, and they're not trading away. When I attempt to trade them on Wonder Trade I get the message "*COMMUNICATION FAILED*"...

---

I also have another Shiny Entei that is Adamant, Pressure Ability, with Stats: 314, 208, 178, 197, 282

- Extreme Speed
- Howl
- Flare Blitz
- Crush Claw

Should I clone this one instead of King Sacred?

Comment: When you say IVs, do you actually mean stats? Because IVs range from 0 to 31.

Comment: You're also missing a stat with each Pokemon. Stats should be in the order HP, Atk, Def, SpA, SpD, Spe

Comment: It would also help if you told us it's Level, as this can be used along with the stats & Nature to calculate the IVs.

Comment: Arceus is shiny-locked, I strongly doubt that it can be wondertraded.

Comment: Level 50 for the first one, level 100 for the second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely you are unable to trade it because you haven't properly set where the Pokemon was caught.

When Powersaving regular Pokemon, a lot of the time this doesn't matter as it can just be set to 'Hatched in <city>' or on some random route, but legendaries you need to be more careful when you set where they are 'caught'.

If your Entei is '6th Generation Born' (has the blue Pentagon in it's Summary Screen) then the only **legal** place that it is allowed to be caught is **Trackless Forest**.

You will need to build another one with it's catch location set to this if you wish to pass them through Wonder Trade.